# error: No WebApplicationContext after adding shiro in my webapp

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to add apache shiro in my spring 4 webapp. It was working fine before i tried to configure shiro. After shiro its throwing error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:252)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

below is my web.xml :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>DECORPOT.COM</display-name>
    <description>Spring MVC web application</description>

    <!-- For web context -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.decorpot.spring.config</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

and my WebConfig.java( i have removed few lines to make it more readable):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.decorpot.datasource.repository", entityManagerFactoryRef = "decorpotEntityManager", transactionManagerRef =     "decorpotTransactionManager")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.decorpot.spring.config", "com.decorpot.spring.controller", "com.decorpot.*" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(); 

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "decorpotDataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "decorpotEntityManager")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.decorpot.datasource.models");

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "decorpotTransactionManager")
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        System.out.println("WebConfig:InternalResourceViewResolver");
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("WebConfig:addResourceHandlers");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/views/**").addResourceLocations("/views/**");
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver factory = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "shiroDatabaseRealm")
    public ShiroDatabaseRealm getShiroRealm() {
        return new ShiroDatabaseRealm();
    }

    @Bean(name = "securityManager")
    public DefaultWebSecurityManager getDefaultWebSecurityManager() {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager dwsm = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        dwsm.setRealm(getShiroRealm());
        return dwsm;
    }

    @Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean getShiroFilterFactoryBean() {
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(getDefaultWebSecurityManager());
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setLoginUrl("/login");
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSuccessUrl("/");
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl("/403");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/example/**", "authc");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/login", "authc");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/**", "authc");
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMap);
        return shiroFilterFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

Is there anything I am missing in my web.xml or configuration for shiro i have messed it up?

Answer (score 0):

seems listener is not able to load your shiroFilter bean.

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>**com.decorpot.spring.WebConfig**</param-value>
</init-param>
```

and add the

```
 <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

A cleaner approach is [explained here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-java-instantiating-container-web)